# How do I add classes to an unspecified amount of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like this should be simple enough but I tend to overthink things. I simply want to add new classes to only the `container-1` elements. The classes need to be numbered to differentiate them. Bonus for multiple methods & explaining in detail as I'd like to learn how to do this properly.

Example:

```html
<div class="scroller">
    <div class="container-1 newClass1"></div>
    <div class="container-1 newClass2"></div>
    <div class="container-2"></div>
    <div class="container-1 newClass3"></div>
    <div class="container-2"></div>
</div>
```

As the title says, the amount can be random. So it needs to read & apply to all `container-1` within the `scroller`.

Comment: Hard choice since every post was good. I learned a bit from each one, so thank you :)   I picked the one I did because I felt like it answered the question the best. Though I ended up using a bit from each post to fit my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one method I can think of is:

```
let selectedContainers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.container-1'));
selectedContainers.map((container, i)=>{
  container.classList.add(`newClass${++i}`)
})
```

What's going on here is that you're selecting all the divs with the container-1 class and creating an array from the NodeList. Then you're mapping through the array to access each element. Using template strings, you add a class name with a dynamic variable being the index of the container. You could use other variables and just increment them after, but I think the index is the easiest solution. Also, the reason I used `++i` is to avoid getting a class with a zero index e.g `newClass0`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some js, which get all elements by class name "container-1". After that in for loop, it will add class "newClass" with counter mark to each of the element with this class.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("container-1");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].classList.add("newClass" + (i+1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector` (just to teach people who still use `jQuery`) to query for `DOM elements`.

You can then use `Array.forEach` to iterate over the list, and use `$node.classList.add` to append a class name.

Just for the purpose of the example:

```js
window.onload = function onload () {
  document.getElementById('btn-add').addEventListener('click', add, true);
  document.getElementById('btn-remove').addEventListener('click', remove, true);
  
}

function add(e) {
  updateFocus(e.target);

  const list = document.querySelectorAll('.container-1');
  list.forEach((item, i) => item.classList.add(`newClass-${i}`));
}

function remove(e) {
  updateFocus(e.target);
  
  const list = document.querySelectorAll('.container-1');
  list.forEach((item, i) => item.classList.remove(`newClass-${i}`));
}

function updateFocus(el){
  document.querySelectorAll('.active').forEach((i) => i.classList.remove('active'));
  el.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.scroller {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div[class*="container"] {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
}

div[class*="newClass-"] {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.active {
  border: 3px solid red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
    <div class="container-1"></div>
    <div class="container-1"></div>
    <div class="container-2"></div>
    <div class="container-1"></div>
    <div class="container-2"></div>
</div>
<button id="btn-add">add newClass-* to container-1</button>
<button id="btn-remove">remove newClass-* to container-1</button>
```

Otherwise it is just one line of code

```
document.querySelectorAll('.container-1');
  .forEach((item, i) => item.classList.add(`newClass-${i}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of all the elements having class name `'container-1` using `document.getElementsByClassName` and the spread operator(`...`). Spread operator is used here because `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection. So to iterate over it easily using a `forEach` we need to convert it to an array. Once converted, we could iterate over it and add `newClass` class to every element. To get the number to be added to the end of each `newClass` we use the 2nd argument to `forEach` which is index of the current element.

```
const containerOneDivs = [...document.getElementsByClassName('container-1')];
containerOneDivs.forEach((div, i) => div.className += ` newClass${i+1}`);
```